# javascript automation for downloading images

Tags: javascript

I am just learning javascript, but I am trying to make a program that downloads the images from a website, where the images are stored in sequential HTMl pages (e.g. www.example.com/23, www.example.com/24). Is there any way to automate this process in javascript? What tools should I look at to get this started? I do want to make my own program (neodownloader was a let down).

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. But to answer anyway, yes this can be automated with server-side javascript, using something like Node.js

Comment: you know the image routes, even if they are a secuence, do you know them?, example: www.example.com/1 to www.example.com/959 ??

Comment: I know my post is very broad. I am just starting with javascript, so I don't know the lingo quite just yet. I do know the image routes, and they are sequential.